# Unwinding nested data responses into structs when a slice is part of the response

Tags: json, go

I'd like to get some input into how you would all go about unwinding nested response data into custom structs. Below is an example of the data i'm being returned. I'm trying to get to the user data.

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/api/v2/user-search/default/test?after=1585612800000&limit=20&offset=0&q=johnsmith%40test.com",
      "type": "application/json"
    }
  },
  "totalCount": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "lastPing": "2020-04-30T02:56:10.430867577Z",
      "environmentId": "xxxx",
      "ownerId": "xxxx",
      "user": {
        "key": "johnsmith@test.com",
        "email": "johnsmith@test.com",
        "firstName": "john",
        "lastName": "smith"
      },
      "_links": {
        "parent": {
          "href": "/api/v2/users/default/test",
          "type": "application/json"
        },
        "self": {
          "href": "/api/v2/users/default/test/johnsmith@test.com",
          "type": "application/json"
        },
        "settings": {
          "href": "/api/v2/users/default/test/johnsmith@test.com/flags",
          "type": "text/html"
        },
        "site": {
          "href": "/default/test/users/johnsmith@test.com",
          "type": "text/html"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently I'm doing the below

```
respData := map[string][]map[string]map[string]interface{}{}
json.Unmarshal(respBody, &respData)

userData := respData["items"][0]["user"]
```

I'd love to be able to unmarshal it into a custom struct but I can't seem to get it to work. The  nested slice that the user object sits within is what keeps throwing me off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type User struct {
    Key       string `json:"key"`
    Email     string `json:"email"`
    FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
    LastName  string `json:"lastName"`
}

type LinkInfo struct {
    Href string `json:"href"`
    Type string `json:"type"`
}

type Item struct {
    LastPing      time.Time `json:"lastPing"`
    EnvironmentID string    `json:"environmentId"`
    OwnerID       string    `json:"ownerId"`
    User          User      `json:"user"`
    Links         LinkInfo  `json:"_links"`
    Self          LinkInfo  `json:"self"`
    Settings      LinkInfo  `json:"settings"`
    Parent        LinkInfo  `json:"parent"`
    Site          LinkInfo  `json:"site"`
}

type ItemDetails struct {
    Links      LinkInfo `json:"_links"`
    TotalCount int      `json:"total_count"`
    Items      []Item
}
```

Can you try this?

https://play.golang.org/p/S_CUN0XEh-d

Answer (score 1):

From what you mentioned it sounds like you were on the right track. Your JSON is pretty large, so let me give you a smaller example similar to the part you mentioned you're having trouble with (the `user` object inside the `items` list).

```
type response struct {
  TotalCount int `json:"totalCount"`
  Items []*itemStruct `json:"items"`
}

type itemStruct struct {
  LastPing string `json:"lastPing"`
  User *userStruct `json:"user"`
}

type userStruct struct {
  Key string `json:"key"`
}
```

Basically to map to a JSON list of objects, just put a field like this in your struct: `Objects []*structWhichMapsToMyObject`

Edit: Here's the code running in Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/EvSvv-2s8y8

Answer (score 1):

If you want this:

```
"user": {
    "key": "johnsmith@test.com",
    "email": "johnsmith@test.com",
    "firstName": "john",
    "lastName": "smith"
}
```

Declare a matching Go struct:

```
type User struct {
    Key       string `json:"key"`
    Email     string `json:"email"`
    FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
    LastName  string `json:"lastName"`
}
```

Then, since the user's parent object looks like this:

```
"items": [
    {
        "lastPing": "2020-04-30T02:56:10.430867577Z",
        "environmentId": "xxxx",
        "ownerId": "xxxx",
        "user": { ... },
        "_links": { ... }
    }
]
```

you also need to declare a matching Go struct for that (you can omit fields you don't need):

```
type Item struct {
    User User `json:"user"`
}
```

and then the parent of the parent:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/api/v2/user-search/default/test?after=1585612800000&limit=20&offset=0&q=johnsmith%40test.com",
            "type": "application/json"
        }
    },
    "totalCount": 1,
    "items": [ ... ]
}
```

and the matching Go struct for the grandparent, again, include only the fields you need:

```
type ResponseData struct {
    Items []Item `json:"items"`
}
```

Once you have this you can decode the json into an instance of `ResponseData`:

```
var rd ResponseData
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &rd); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
for _, item := range rd.Items {
    fmt.Println(item.User)
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/7yavVSBcHQP